# GWT: How to prevent any canvas or drawingArea from stopping all mouse events from reaching everything in front of it?

Tags: gwt, canvas, mouseevent, vector-graphics

I desperately need to be able to use functioning GWT Widgets placed in front of a drawing surface, like this:

```
absolutePanel.add(canvas); //drawing surface, for drawing other things
absolutePanel.setWidgetPosition(canvas, 0, 0);
absolutePanel.add(myWidget);
absolutePanel.setWidgetPosition(myWidget, 0, 0); //i.e. in front
```

However the drawing surface blocks ALL mouse events reaching the "myWidget", even though "myWidget" is in front! How do I ensure "myWidget" can still receive mouse events? I desperately need this as, in my case, I need to be able to draw special connector lines between widgets using the drawing surface behind them. This used to work with Firefox, GWT 2.3 and Windows XP, although I don't know why.

I definitely have this problem on IE and Chrome (Windows Vista) and GWT 2.4, whether I use Canvas or Vaadin gwt-graphics's DrawingArea, (although I can't test Firefox because the GWT plug-in isn't up to it right now). Anyone have the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DOM.setCapture to forward all input to a specific element.

You could call DOM.setCapture(myWidget.getElement()) and at some later point release it back DOM.releaseCapture(myWidget.getElement());

Comment: How and where would I use it in this specific context?

Comment: When would you recommend I do "set" and when would I do "release"?

Comment: Also, are there any other possibilities for routing events other than this?

Comment: in general should take a look at who is consuming the event (stopping propagation) and fix this.

Comment: It's clearly the drawing area, so how would I fix this specifically?

Comment: Daniel, your solution doesn't work for me at all unfortunately (yet). I tried putting "DOM.setCapture(myWidget.getElement())" in myWidget's "onLoad" to no avail. Do I need to put it somewhere else? Just to clarify, when there's no drawing surface behind it, "myWidget" receives mouse events just fine.

Comment: Correction, it causes events to fire out of turn on that widget, not what I'm looking for at all. e.g. it carries out the "mouseOver" and "mouseOut" upon seemingly every other mouse event (even mouseMove) even when the mouse isn't even over that widget. Do you have another solution?